# Translating a curve in openCv from ROI to frame

Tags: c++, opencv, math, matrix

I'm currently working on a project, where i use opencv to find a curve in an image. Therefor i set a region of interest, to where I'm looking for the curve. Now my problem is that when i calculate the parameters of my polynomial (lets say 2nd degree), I use the relative coordinates from the ROI, but i want to translate the parameters of the function (which are stored in a cv::Mat) to the original image.
The solution I'm looking for should work for any degree polynomial.

To be more precise I have the function parameters of the polynomial relative to my ROI, but i want the parameters relative to the original image.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the polynomial is a function *f(x)*. Then *g(x) = f(x) + a* moves it *a* units vertically (positive a moves the function up).

Function h(x) = f(x - b)* moves the function horizontally (positive *b* moves the function to the right).

Therefore, to move your polynomial b units horizontally and a units vertically you should define the transform as *T(x, a, b) = f(x-b) + a*

In your case, a = roi.y; and b = roi.x; provided that image coordinates start form 0,0.

Here is a link to an interactive demo I made. You can test this for different functions and move the sliders.
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fezybrsyhw

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But now i want to get rid of a and b in my transformed function. I can simply add a to the constant term of f' . But what about b. So let me get a little bit more precise: If f has the parameters p1, p2 ... pn . And f' p'1 , p'2 and so on. How do i calculate p'n  so i don't have that x-b . For example f\left(x\right)\ =\ 0.5x^2+x-2 should be transformed with b = 1. The transformed function could be written as h\left(x\right)\ =\ 0.5x^2-2.5\ \ .

Comment: You'd have to reduce the function to simplest possible version. There are algorithms for that but I can't see why'd you do that since it would have significant impact on the performance.